# Android custom camera magnify preview

Tags: android, android-camera, zooming, surfaceview, magnify

I have a custom camera application with the deprecated camera api and a surfaceview. I want to be able to magnify the live feed returned from the camera. I have tried with zoom but I am only limited to the maximum zoom value which is normally 4x but I want more than that. Any ideas on how to do that? I know it is possible because of an app called 30x Zoom in google play. How is that possible? What am I missing?

Comment: so they are doing software zoom, arent they?

Comment: Well it looks like a well enhanced digital zoom applied

Comment: so try using `TextureView` instead of `SurfaceView`

Comment: I am trying to use the textureview but I don't know how to apply the zoom transformation

Comment: `setTransform` ;-)

Comment: no I know that, I am talking about the matrix, I don't know how to specify that one for zoom